# NG Options select based on object name

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-options, using an array of objects with the objects name property as the label.

When I first load the module, the ng-module contains an object with is foreign to the array but shares the same properties.  How to I get the ng-options to recognise this and select the correct option?

So :

```
var options = [{name:'test'},{name:'test2'}];
```

they go into the ng-options like so

```
ng-options="options.name for option in options "
```

and the model is set in the controller like so

```
$scope.modelVar = {name:'test'};
```

Comment: It can't differentiate between an object and an array - the syntaxes are different

Comment: No, they're both objects, same properties, just referenced separately.

Comment: Post some relevant code if you can

Comment: relevant code posted